# Adding Okta Authentication to a SPA app which uses a Micronaut Server running Graphql

Tags: java, security, micronaut, okta, okta-api

We have a single page application (Angular JS) and we have configured the SPA application to use the okta authorization. We have a backend serving data via Graphql which is written in Java using Micronaut Server. How to setup the authentication for backend in this case ?
Should I create another application in okta and setup a web server or Is there way I can use the token generated in SPA application and pass it down to backend and verify it.

## Edit

Based on the comments I have used the bearer token generated from the SPA application to authorize the backend query. Used the Micronaut-security-jwt library and configured to hit my okta service. It worked. now the only question remaining how to add an authentication to graphql controller. Graphql path is configured via application.yml, I am not sure how to add the Secured annotation to the Graphql controller.

Following setting is configuration used in application yml -

```
security:
  enabled: true
  token:
    jwt:
      enabled: true
      claims-validators:
        issuer: https://dev-xxx.okta.com/oauth2/default
      signatures:
        jwks:
          okta:
            url: https://dev-xx.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/keys
```

Comment: Have you checked this guide? https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-oauth2-okta.html Any issues with it? And you don't have to create another app. Just use the same token obtained by your SPA

Comment: Yes I started with that. Here in the Java Gradle example. They are creating a "Web Application" in okta. In that case they got a client secret along client id. In our case we created an SPA applcation which doesn't have a client secret. So I was hoping there would be some way that the bearer token generated in the SPA application can be used for authentication. 

I was not able to find a guide for that why got confused.

Comment: you need to read µN guide about JWT security - https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-security/latest/guide/#jwt there should be a section describing what to configure to perform token validation